# why do my tail lights and brake lights remain on when 95' honda accord is turned off?

Tags: honda

i've replaced brake light bumper switch, hazard and tail light relay and tail light switch but still didn't fix my problem. Have to take the fuse out to keep from battery draining. Is it an electrical issue? and how do i fix it

Comment: Have you checked all your fuses?  A blown fuse can do odd, unrelated things in some cars.  And is the center-mount brake light also on?

Comment: @JPhi1618  Ignition switch issue possibility too?

Comment: yes the center mount brake also stays on. all lights work. will check fuses. ignition switches can cause that problem also?

Comment: If the center mount light wasn't on, I would suspect the headlight switch or possibly ignition.  The high-mount should _only_ come on when your foot is on the brake, so as long as the brake pedal switch is good (test it), I'd look at fuses next.

Comment: Are you positive the brake light switch is adjusted properly?  If you disconnect the switch, do the lights stay on?

Comment: What fuse or fuses are you removing to the lights to shut off?

Comment: possibly a faulty trailer lighting connector?

Answer (score 2):

You should list the body style, things can be different depending on body style.

On some Hondas there will be a brake light failure sensor somewhere in the back of the car either in the trunk or behind a light. Looking at a wiring diagram there seems to be one behind the left tail light on your Accord.

With the fuse installed test for power on the green-white wire (input voltage). If power exists and the brake switch is in the open position/pedal not depressed. Than it may likely be a fault in the multiplex unit/fuse box.

Answer (score 0):

One likely cause for the brake lights staying on is a brake pedal switch that remains in the closed position, which keeps the brake lights on.

This switch is situated next to the brake pedal and if the brake pedal doesn't make contact with the switch, the switch stays closed, which keeps the lights on.

One would need to refer to a wiring diagram to confirm whether this also explains why the tail lights stay on.